# Non zero continuous path $[0,1]\to \mathbb C$ has continuous logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, logarithms, uniform-convergence

Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb C$ be continuous, and not passing through $0$. How can we prove that, using complex analysis, there is a continuous $G:[0,1]\to \mathbb C$ so that $\gamma=e^G$ ?

This can be done in the $C^1$ case, using $G(x)=\int_0^x\gamma'(t)/\gamma(t)dt$. To pass to the more general continuous case, one can convole $\gamma$ with a mollifier, $\gamma_r=\gamma*\phi_r$, so that $\gamma_r=e^{G_r}$.  $\gamma_r$ converges to $\gamma$ uniformly, as $r\to 0$, but I do not know if the $G_r$ will also converge uniformly. If they did, then the uniform limit would be a continuous function $G$, and $\gamma=e^G$.

Comment: Yes, there is such a $G$. No need to mollify. Do you know some covering theory? By the path-lifting property $\gamma$ lifts to the universal covering of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think you mean that $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb C^*$ can be lifted to $G:[0,1]\to \mathbb C$ because the exponential map $\mathbb C\to \mathbb C^*$ is a covering projection?

Comment: Yes, embarrassing typo.

Comment: @DanielFischer Don't worry about it. As it happens, I am familiar with the algebraic topology going behind the scenes here, but as the problem was posed in a complex analysis class, I would expect there to be a pure analysis answer, following those lines.

Comment: Using mollifiers is pretty uncommon in complex analysis. The typical "topology-free" proof would more or less be the proof of the path-lifting property for the map $\exp \colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. There is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\gamma([t,t+\varepsilon])$ is contained in an open set on which holomorphic branches of $\log$ exist, for all $t\in [0,1-\varepsilon]$, then you split $[0,1]$ into finitely many subintervals of length $\leqslant \varepsilon$, and choose your branches of the logarithm so that the $\log\circ\gamma$ fit together.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's pretty much exactly the proof of the path-lifting property. I was wondering if one could reduce the continuous case to the $C^1$ case, and then use the standard arguments described in my question.

Comment: Yes, it's the proof of the path-lifting property in the special case of $\exp$. It's the standard argument if you can't directly appeal to covering theory. Avoiding it is not easy. If you try to show that $G_r \to G$ uniformly when $\gamma_r \to \gamma$ uniformly, I don't (yet, at least) see how to completely avoid the principal idea of that argument either.